# creating the column based on values from other column in pandas + iteration

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have data frame.

Additionally I have 2 lists:

```
se_bench = []
tu_bench= []
```

I want to create the function like:

```
def calculation(row):
    if row['var_1'] == #something:
        return (se_bench[1]/tu_bench[1])* turnover.iloc[i,]

    elif row['var_1'] == #something else:
        return (se_bench[2]/tu_bench[2])* turnover.iloc[i,]

df.apply(lambda row: calculation(row),axis = 1)
```

where 'var_1' and 'turnover' are variables in data frame.
How can I iterate `turnover.iloc[i,]` through each row?

I think, it is possible to do it by for loop, but is it possible to do it with apply function?

**EDIT:**

with for loop it works something like it:

```
#Or alternative:
se = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df['var_1'] == #something:
        seva.append((se_bench[1]/tu_bench[1])* turnover.iloc[i,])

    elif row['var_1'] == #something else:
        seva.append((se_bench[1]/tu_bench[1])* turnover.iloc[i,])

    else:
        seva.append(np.nan)


df['seva'] = pd.Series(seva,index = df.index)
```

Comment: In the above code `turnover.iloc[i,]` should be `df.turnover.iloc[i,]` if `turnover` is a variable/column in `df`. Also I hope you know that doing `df['var_1']==` is comparing series and if you wants to compare values then in the loop code it should be again using `iloc`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [df.applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function which applies a function to whole dataframe and is much efficient than writing a loop iterating over the rows.

`df.applymap(lambda x: calculation(x))`

should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculation(row):
    if row['var_1'] == #something:
        return (se_bench[1]/tu_bench[1])* row['turnover']

    elif row['var_1'] == #something else:
        return (se_bench[2]/tu_bench[2])* row['turnover']

    else:
         return (np.nan)    

df['seva'] = df.apply(calculation, axis = 1)
```